# I want to use Gridview as input fields, with no data to begin with. Is there an easy way to do this?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

Thank you in advance.

Using .NET and VB I am looking to use Gridview as an input form grid with checkboxes.  I would like each person who fills out the form to have a unique entry in the DB so the data source would be empty.  Is there any way to display the checkboxes and have the gridview show up without any source data?  We are trying to stay away from dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your columns in the EmptyDataTemplate

http://forums.asp.net/p/1436652/3240106.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2006/05/04/77151.aspx

Answer (score 0):

please refer to below articles that would explain how to show a grid header when there is no data. then you can simply hide/unhide footer row where you can enter data and save the data.

http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/11/how-to-add-footerrow-to-gridview-which-has-no-value-initially/

http://technico.qnownow.com/2012/06/07/show-grid-header-when-there-are-no-rows-in-gridview-control/